# Оn/off all markers in several groups separately and all groups at once on the leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have three groups of markers, and I would like them to be turned on / off separately, and all at once.
I'm trying to transfer the function from the example, but I don’t know how to do it right for my marker groups. I will be grateful for the answer.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/qkvo7hav/7/
My map: http://breamap.hostronavt.ru/

```
// Marker group
    var Group_1 = L.layerGroup(); 
    // Group_1 markers
    var Group_2 = L.layerGroup(); 
    // Group_2 markers
    var Group_3 = L.layerGroup(); 
    // Group_3 markers

    var Markers_overlays = {
        "1": Group_1,};
        "2": Group_2,};
        "3": Group_3,};

    // empty LayerGroup that will be used to emulate adding/removing all markers 
    var allPointsLG = L.layerGroup();
        Markers_overlays["All Points"] = allPointsLG;

    // control.layers
    var Markers_control_topright = L.control.layers(null, Markers_overlays, {collapsed: true, position: 'topright'}).addTo(map);        
        Markers_overlays["1"].addTo(map);
        Markers_overlays["2"].addTo(map);   
        Markers_overlays["3"].addTo(map);

    // adding/removing all markers method from https://jsfiddle.net/qkvo7hav/7/
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation [layers-control](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/)

Comment: Of course, but it works if the marker group is one. I have three groups of markers, and I would like them to be turned on / off separately, and all at once.

Comment: A marker group can contain other marker groups

Comment: The problem is that this checkbox will get out-of-sync when user toggles individual categories. 
A more complicated trick is to keep your master Layer Group empty, and emulate the addition / removal of all other category Layer Groups by listening to the map overlayadd and overlayremove events and manually adding / removing the categories.
Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/qkvo7hav/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, this is not exactly how it should be but for a good start it should be enough;)

```js
let citiesA = L.layerGroup();
let citiesB = L.layerGroup();
let test = L.layerGroup();

L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(citiesA),
  L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(citiesA),
  L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(citiesA),
  L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(citiesA);

L.marker([39.81, -105.09]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(citiesB),
  L.marker([39.64, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(citiesB),
  L.marker([39.63, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(citiesB),
  L.marker([39.57, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(citiesB);


let mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
  '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
  'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw';


let grayscale = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
    id: 'mapbox.light',
    attribution: mbAttr
  }),
  streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    attribution: mbAttr
  });

let map = L.map('map', {
  center: [39.73, -104.99],
  zoom: 10,
  layers: [grayscale]
});

let baseLayers = {
  Grayscale: grayscale,
  Streets: streets
};

let overlays = {
  CitiesA: citiesA,
  CitiesB: citiesB,
  'All cities': test
};

overlays['All cities'].on('add', function() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  for (let overlay in overlays) {
    overlays[overlay].addTo(map);
  }
 }, 0);
});

overlays['All cities'].on('remove', function() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  for (let overlay in overlays) {
    map.removeLayer(overlays[overlay]);
  }
 }, 0);
});

let control = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is not important, but it does not work in IE11.388 ... But this example works: https://jsfiddle.net/qkvo7hav/7/. However, thank you very much again.

Comment: It doesn't work because I used the **arrow function** I have already returned to the Middle Ages ;) And it works under IE 11;) I suggest writing the code in the latest javascript syntax and converting to es2015 using babel + corejs

Comment: It sounds great, but not comprehensible to me :)) Thanks anyway...